# Set visibility of TextView in android not working

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, textview

My program runs into a runtime exception when I try to make the view 'GONE'.
My code that handles it:

```
setContentView(R.layout.list_main);
... 
 lv =  getListView();
             View header = (View) findViewById(R.id.header_layout_root);
             TextView tv = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.new_highscore);
            tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);

 lv = getListView();
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View header = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_header, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.header_layout_root));
        lv.addHeaderView(header, null, false);

mC = mDBHelper.getAllHighScores();
        startManagingCursor(mC);

        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, mC, 
                new String[] { DBAdapter.COL_NAME, DBAdapter.COL_SCORE }, 
                new int[] { R.id.txtText1, R.id.txtText2 });
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

xml:

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:id="@+id/header_layout_root"
  android:background="#ffffff"
  android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Pick Master High Scores"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="28dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp">
</TextView>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:id="@+id/header_layout_root1">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/sample_image"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/pickmaster"
        android:scaleType="fitXY">
    </ImageView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/new_highscore"
        android:text="New High Score added!"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:background="#AA000000"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/sample_image">
    </TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is, I think, that new_highscore is not in list_main, but it is in another xml file. I am using two as I have a listview with a header and image etc.

Any ideas on making the view 'invisible' or just 'gone'?

Thanks,

Ben

Comment: how do you use xml file with R.id.new_highscore?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Try this code**

```
   lv = getListView();
   LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
   View header = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_header, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.header_layout_root));
   lv.addHeaderView(header, null, false);
   View relativeLayout = header.findViewById(R.id.header_layout_root1);
   TextView highScore = relativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.new_highscore);
   highScore.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

**Remove this code from the top**

```
lv =  getListView();
View header = (View) findViewById(R.id.header_layout_root);
TextView tv = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.new_highscore);
tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

If that doesn't work, please post the exception your are encountering.

Comment: I tried this, it didnt work... I have updated the code to show how I assign listview

Comment: Thanks Justin, I have changed the code and some other errors seem to be coming up. not when accessed directly (ie view highscores button) but when i add a score, pass the variable to the new activity and then show highscores. I get these errors, it is after the starttAcvtvity and before the subsequent onCreate.

Comment: WARN/WindowManager(1377): Previous dispatch state: {{KeyEvent{action=1 code=4 repeat=0 meta=0 scancode=158 mFlags=8} to Window{45004ae8 com.test.frequencyTest/com.test.frequencyTest.Menu paused=false} @ 1319733312935 lw=Window{45004ae8 com.test.frequencyTest/com.test.frequencyTest.Menu paused=false} lb=android.os.BinderProxy@45004928 fin=false gfw=true ed=true tts=0 wf=false fp=false mcf=Window{45004ae8 com.test.frequencyTest/com.test.frequencyTest.Menu paused=false}}}

Comment: Error was my mistake, was in the manifest. You're solution saved the day :)

Comment: If I could do two vote ups, you would've gotten it today. Thanks much man! Did vote it up once.

Answer (score -1):

can't you have just one xml with a textview and a listview bellow . then it should work

Comment: I want to use LayoutInflater in the way it is implemented