# How to Visible/Invisible using OnClickListener?

Tags: java, android-studio

I am working on FAQ page I don't want to use Expandable list view and stuff.
So I set 2 TextViews(1 for Question and 1 for Answer) and made one clickable.

[image: working onclick]

The above image shows when the first textview mfaq is clicked it sets second one mAns to visible.

The below code works well to Set the mAns textview visible:

```
public class faq extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView mfaq,mAns;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_faq);

    mfaq=findViewById(R.id.faq);
    mAns=findViewById(R.id.ans);

    mfaq.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        int counter=0; //setting counter to count onclick
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ++counter; //incrementing counter first click
            if(counter==1){
                mAns.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            //this sets mAns visible , but when i click on it again i want it to hide the text view
            counter=0; //resetting the counter
        }
    });
}
}
```

So I want to set the visibilty to gone when the textview is clicked again(Should function like Click-visible,ClickAgain-Invisible,Repeat).
Note-I am a beginner please try to explain me what the code is doing so I learn more :)
Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set visibility of TextView in android not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917093/set-visibility-of-textview-in-android-not-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well you wanna hide/show your textview each time you click on the other text?

```
            mfaq.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (mAns.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
                    mAns.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                else
                    mAns.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             }
        });
```

Comment: Hey Stefan, majdi can u help me over this question please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66045709/how-to-fix-this-margin-gap